# Duvidas Abstract Factory

Tags: java, design-pattern, factory

Estou com esse exercicio para fazer porem não estou conseguindo fazer a implementação

Utilizando o Padrão Abstract Factory, implemente em java clientes dos produtos Gerenciador de Processos e Gerenciador de Memoria , para os Sistemas Operacionais Linux, Mac , e Windows

Ate agora so consegui fazer Isso, estou com muitas duvidas de como terminar esse codigo  :

```
public class FabricaWindows implements FabricadeGerenciador {

@Override
public void Gerenciadordeprocesso() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void Gerenciadordememoria() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



public class FabricaLinux implements FabricadeGerenciador {

@Override
public void Gerenciadordeprocesso() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void Gerenciadordememoria() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}

public interface FabricadeGerenciador {
void Gerenciadordeprocesso();
void Gerenciadordememoria();
}




public interface Gerenciadordememoria {

}
public interface Gerenciadordeprocesso {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema da sua implementação são os retornos dos métodos. O AbstractFactory é um padrão que serve justamente para criar objetos, nesse caso uma família de objetos. Portanto os métodos `void Gerenciadordeprocesso();` e `void Gerenciadordememoria();` deveriam possuir retornos. O correto seria:

```
public interface FabricadeGerenciador {
    Gerenciadordememoria Gerenciadordeprocesso();
    Gerenciadordeprocesso Gerenciadordememoria();
}
```

Com isso, seu código seria utilizado da seguinte forma:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    FabricadeGerenciador fabrica = new FabricaWindows();
    Gerenciadordememoria gerenciadorMemoria = fabrica.Gerenciadordememoria();
    Gerenciadordeprocesso gerenciadorProcesso = fabrica.Gerenciadordeprocesso();
}
```

Dicas:

1. Os métodos do `AbstractFactory` são métodos de criação, portanto seria interessante utilizar nomes mais apropriados, por exemplo, `criarGerenciadorMemoria`.
2. Nome de método em java deve começar com letra minúscula e deve seguir o padrão de nomenclatura camel case. Ou seja, o nome `Gerenciadordeprocesso` está fora do padrão. O correto seria `gerenciadorDeProcesso`.
3. Nome de classe e interface segue parecido com o camel case, só que o nome deve começar com letra maiúscula. Esse padrão é chamado de pascal case. Ou seja, ao invés de `Gerenciadordememoria`, deveria ser `GerenciadorDeMemoria` .